# Vertically align text next to an image in <td>

Tags: html, css, email

Hello I am making simple mailing and have a trouble.

I can't align text next to image in

```
<td width="433" style="color:#707177; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-align:left; width:433px;" valign="middle">
  <img alt="email" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-icon-set-free-pack/48/Streamline-18-128.png" height="15" width="15" style="vertical-align:middle;">
  <span style="color:#707177;font-size:14px;">000 000 000</span>
</td>
```

I've created [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8va7zLdn/).

I can't use something like `<td><img /></td><td>text</td>`

Comment: How about `vertical-align:text-top;` instead of `vertical-align:middle;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to your span. It's a small difference, but it works.

```
<span class="feed" style="color:#707177;font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;">000 000 000</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8va7zLdn/1/

Comment: Run the code, it's actually already done. It just does not look like it is aligned due to the height of the image. Compare it to your old one.

Comment: this does not work if there is a lot of text inside the span and the text gets one or more linebreaks. use a background-image on the td instead!